# Ambiguous reference to member joined()

Tags: swift, xcode, debugging

Join String error, trying to cast AnyHashable as NSManagedObject which seemed to work in Xcode 3.

The error shown:

[image: error]

and the NSManagedObject model being casted

[image: model]

and the NSManagedObject model

[image: model]

Comment: What's the type of `feed.category`?

Comment: On Xcode 3 time there was no Swift. Also, how you want to cast Set to a FeedCategory? Set = An unordered collection of unique elements | FeedCategory = CoreData object.

Comment: @user28434 Sorry feed.category info would be helpful, adding now

Comment: @DeryckLucian to be honest I am debugging someone's code, I have no idea how they set this in the first place

Comment: Ok, it looks like `feed.category` is `Optional<Set<AnyHashable>>`, and you're doing `map` over `Optional`, not over `Set`. You should start with putting `?` between `feed.category` and `.map`.

Comment: ^_^ @user28434 the simplest fixes are always the hardest to see. Thank you a million.